# Reverse singly linked list in python without using a temporary variable

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to solve some problems on Leetcode.

I completed the Reverse Linked List problem, which basically requires you to reverse a singly linked list. My solution is this:

```py
def reverseList(self, head):
    curr = head
    prev = None
    if head != None:
        while (curr.next):
            temp = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = temp
        curr.next = prev
    return curr
```

**I used a temp value** to keep track of the original NEXT node after the current node, before the value of the NEXT node is changed in the following line.

However, when I compare my solution to other solutions, it seems that there was no need for a temporary value at all. Below is a sample solution:

```py
def reverseList(self, head):
    curr, prev = head, None
    while curr:
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = curr.next
    return prev
```

No temporary value was used, which I am trying to figure out why. The below image is my mental visualisation of what happens in the solution:

[image]

Why is it possible for the code to be able to still assign `curr = curr.next` (line 4 of solution) after `curr.next` was mutated? (line 6 of solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right, the second solution is just not working.

Comment: Damn I should have just tested it out myself to see if it was working, oh well.

Answer (score 1):

@lambert has it right.

The particular solution you compare to here does not reverse anything. It takes a long way around shifting the linked list into a new variable.